# Reversing equal sized chunks of a list

Tags: python

If I have a list:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3]
```

My goal is to split it into equal sized chunks of `n`, reverse each chunk, and then put the chunks back in order. So, for the example above, for chunk size 4, I'd get:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3] 
[_________]  [_________] [________]  [______]
     |            |           |          | 
     1            2           3          4 (this is smaller than 4 but receives the same treatment)

                     ||

[4, 3, 2, 1,    4, 3, 2, 1,      4, 3, 2, 1,     3, 2, 1]
```

This is what I have:

```
n = 4
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3] 
chunks = [l[i : i + n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]
print(chunks)
# [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3]]

for i in range(len(chunks)):
    chunks[i] = list(reversed(chunks[i])) # or chunks[i] = chunks[i][::-1]

from functools import reduce
out = list(reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, chunks))

print(out)
# [4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1]
```

I don't think this is very good though. Is there another way that better utilises python's libraries than this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about using the following list comprehension:

```
[x for i in range(0,len(l),4) for x in reversed(l[i:i+4])]
```

or with parameterized chunk size:

```
chunk = 4
[x for i in range(0,len(l),chunk) for x in reversed(l[i:i+chunk])]
```

This generates:

```
>>> [x for i in range(0,len(l),4) for x in reversed(l[i:i+4])]
[4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1]
```

for your given list. Furthermore I guess it is quite declarative (the `reversed(..)` indicates that you reverse, etc.)

Comment: Yesssss this is it.

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension sure looks nice, but perhaps it is more readable to simply do a for loop and update each chunk by itself:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3]
chunk = 4

for i in range(0, len(lst), chunk):
    lst[i:i+chunk] = reversed(lst[i:i+chunk])

print(lst)
# [4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1]
```

If you do not want the update in place, you can do `out = lst[:]` at the start.